Make pure-ftp only accept virtual users
I installed pure-ftpd on Debian (Raspberry Pi), found the config file and managed to do basic configuration, disallow anonymous login, create a virtual user, call pure-pw mkdb and restart the server. But I can't login with this user.
Instead I can login with a regular Linux user.
I would like to reject regular users and only accept virtual users.
I found that I should start the server with the -l parameter that specifies which logins should be accepted. This sounds great - if only I could find where the server is started. There is nothing in init.d and other known (to me) places that do such automatic daemon starts. As far as I know I did nothing to activate the daemon, this must have happened at the installation process.
If someone could tell me where pure-ftpd is started, perhaps this would solve both of my problems.
I wonder why a lot of stuff can be configured in the config file but such basic configuration like which users to accept must be set in a completely different way. What is the reason?
Is pure-ftpd not the best choice for an ftp server that only should accept dedicated users with no relation to system users?
Why FTP?
I want to transfer images from my smartphone to the Raspberry Pi in the internal network, not accessible from outside. So FTP seems to be a good choice, especially because I expect a server that is described as "designed for security" to provide encrypted transfers too.
With original configuration it seems to be open to every Linux user which makes me doubt this security a bit.
Why this FTP server?
I tried other FTP servers too but I didn't like they are tied to normal users. I don't want to add system users and assign home directories to them. I simply want to add two FTP users that can access one directory and save files as the user of this directory. I am not (yet) sure if this works, I'm going step by step and I am hanging at the virtual users for now.
Documentation is not hard to find but most appears incomplete to me. In this case they all tell how to add a virtual user, but I had to search a while until I found I have to activate that. But no comment about where to activate that.

You don't need FTP for that. There's plenty of file managers for your Android or iOs phone that support SMB – windows file shares – and samba would allow you to set up users in a number of ways, most of which are not tied to the users in /etc/passwd. But the question really is why you're not simply sticking with SSH/SFTP (that sounds similar, but is unrelated to FTP): sure, that's bound to your system user, but how is that less secure, really? SSH is really well understood, and it's used to securely access high-profile servers all over the world.

Why this FTP server: hm, as said, the other large ones do support what you call virtual users as well. I'd have to say that pure-ftpd's documentation was not as good, either. I'd call it worse, compared to proftpd's rather well-structured docs (read the "howtos" -> "ConfigFile", where they explain virtual users), but I guess that is subjective enough that you and me can very reasonably disagree on that!


I  wonder why a lot of stuff can be configured in the config file but such basic configuration like which users to accept must be set in a completely different way. What is the reason?

It's just written that way. In general, "why is software XYZ doing A and not the technically equally possible B?" is answered just like "why did the author write his book to be A and not B": it was a conscious or unconscious decision, and nobody has gotten around to do B with that software instead.
In this case, it's a design decision (which I don't share, but you chose pure-ftpd probably exactly for their design decisions):

Pure-FTPd strives to remain simple to operate, and keeps the number of
knobs down to a minimum.
Virtually everything can be set using command-line switches, so that a
configuration file is not required.

So, that's why things aren't consistently in one configuration file from the upstream pure-ftpd side.
Having to add command line options to do the thing you want is (obviously, but only obvious to people who have to package the software and help thousands of users get it running, not to the software authors themselves) a bad idea; so, in debian, a "wrapper" PERL script is used, which reads its own config files and then call pure-ftpd as the user wants it to.
It's started in /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd, which is part of the pure-ftpd-common debian package, which you should have gotten if you installed pure-ftpd properly (i.e., through your OS'es package manager, apt install pure-ftpd). If you didn't install it through that, well, you get to set up your own daemon starting mechanism! (don't do that. Use the distro package.)
The script is /usr/bin/pure-ftpd-wrapper (might be reading the available config options in the beginning, but don't modify it!), and it reads all files in the /etc/pure-ftpd/conf directory for general configuration, and all in /etc/pure-ftpd/auth for authentication configuration. You'll hence find the settings mentioned in /usr/bin/pure-ftpd-wrapper as file names in /etc/pure-ftps/{conf,auth}.
Do I think this makes for an "easy to use FTP server"? No. But it might still be a sensible choice if you really need FTP (not an expert in FTP servers, to be honest); people usually prefer (at least in my experienced based on the post I've seen on here) ProFTP or vsftp. I'd personally argue that it's 2024, and the only place I see FTP being used in significant deployments is in malware and warez distribution, so, I'd argue that if you're going as far as having a complicated setup with virtual users, maybe FTP is too 1970s for your needs, and you'd be better off with SFTP / webdav / S3-compatible protocols… which don't lug around five decades of compatibility (FTP is literally older than the internet. It predates the internet protocol by three years). I'd argue even SMB would be more sensible, and can these days be properly encrypted and secured to work over the internet. Unlike FTP, all these protocols support proper encoding support, support for continuing interrupted transfers, much better directory listings…

Well some things really are "just written that way" while others have a good reason to be as they are, and knowing this reason makes that thing really handy. "simple to operate" - yes I wish it was :-) If there is a config file (which I prefer over cryptic parameters, especially if one has to dig into generated files in case of a daemon) then it is hard to understand why only a subset of options is present there.

I have added paragraphs to my question that tell more about why FTP. I also tried the other options you mentioned, but documentation wasn't so straightforward for them too.
